# Where are the Pentaho version 8.0 Snapshots?

Tags: pentaho, nexus

Are the Pentaho 8.0 Snapshots available somewhere?  When I use `http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni` I get errors like

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: pentaho-reporting-engine:pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core:jar:8.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If I search on the nexus itself for `pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core` it shows that latest version is 7.0.0.6-95 and some 7.1 QAT version.

Is there another nexus for Snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

The reporting engine jars changed groupId when the project build structure was changed.

The new group id is org.pentaho.reporting.engine. That specific jar product id is classic-core.

You can view the published dependencies here:

https://public.nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic-core/

hope that helps.

Comment: Is this what you're asking for?
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pentaho.reporting.engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>classic-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>